# Connectionless Client/Server Strategies (UDP) - .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

NOTE:  This is one-way UDP transmission (i.e. no return path)--I CANNOT send data back to the client.

At this point, I've written a few client/server combinations all with a mix of good and bad results for packet delivery on the server-side using the .NET UDPClient class.  Here is a synopsis of them:

1. Single, blocking thread/single port (.Receive()):  Works well except unless I slow down transmission of data, I inevitably lose a small amount of packets which makes the resulting file unusable.
2. Single, async thread/single port (.BeginReceive()):  Same as above -- I miss packets if I don't throttle back the sender (client).
3. Multi-thread, multi-ports:  I create 100 threads (random number) and set a static port range (e.g. 10001-10100).  Had to change the client to dynamically walk through sending across different ports.  This seems to work well in initial testing but presented new problems (e.g. file locking issues trying to log across the different threads).

At this point, since I'm using UDP and can't get missed packets re-transmitted, I'm leaning towards option 3.  For option 3, does anyone see additional problems of concern (besides the access-contention issues I'm already experiencing)?

Is anyone aware of any other strategy to employ for the server to minimize the possibility of losing packets to a non-ready UDP listener?

Comment: Usually you put one dedicated thread to read incoming messages and put them into some queue, as fast as possible. Other threads can then (leasurely) empty the queue and process the data. Increasing the `ReciveBufferSize` will help avoiding discarded messages for some transient slowdown of your app. Btw, using UDP "one-way" to transmit files seems like a horrible idea unless the data received is pretty irrelevant anyhow. If a message is lost, the client will never know... If the messages don´t contain some kind of message counter, the server will save a fdile and never know its corrupted.

Comment: @C.Gonzalez, thanks for your input.  Yes, I'm familiar with common connection-oriented data queuing techniques--I'm just running into unique issues that average TCP listeners never have to account for.  If the TCP Listener isn't available, TCP/IP handles detection of the missing packet and re-transmission of it.  In UDP I don't have that.  I've overcome (or at least greatly minimized) the other concerns you mentioned.  There's nothing I can do about dropped packets due to network but I can handle missing information due to a non-ready listener.  I think I've solved the access contention too.

Comment: Don't use UDPClient class.  The best way to do this is with IOCP, a large buffer and a dedicated and priortised thread writing the incoming stream to a continuous shared memory "loop" buffer.  Then some lower priority threads accessing and reading the shared memory buffer.